# Iterating JSON file and not returning result correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, validation

I have a JSON file and iterating it. If there is a column called "validation" : {"required"} then I add a count in a variable like below:

```
for (var a= 0; a<66; ++a) {
        var requiredFieldsInPart = 0;

            for (var b=0; b<$scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields.length; ++b) {
             try {
                 throw console.log($scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[b]["validations"]["required"]);
             }
             catch (e) {
                 console.log(e);
             }
             requiredFieldsInPart += 1;
         }
```

The reason I'm using try/catch is because I wanna pass if there is an error. There are some objects which do not have "validations" attribute so it was causing an error.

Let's say there are total 21 fields in a section and 19 of them have `"validations"` and 2 do not have `"validations"`. So `requiredFieldsInPart` should return 19. However, it returns 21 right now. How do I make sure it only counts an object with `"validations"`??

Comment: I don't think you understand how try, catch and throw works...

Comment: That is a really convoluted approach to a simple task. You could just do `if( $scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[b].validations && $scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[b].validations.required ) { requiredFieldsInPart++; }` and leave the try/catch out.

Comment: @lerouche can you provide some explanation where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, what is $scope? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: Secondly, how are you avoiding errors by `throw`ing on every iteration?

Comment: ` "validation" : {"required"} ` is not valid javascript syntax.

Comment: Thirdly, please do not just catch all errors and move on. Not only is it slow and overkill, you could catch unknown/unexpected errors. If you really just want to test if a property exists, just check that it's truthy or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would proceed by filtering the source array and returning the size of the result :

```
return $scope.groups.filter(group =>
                             group.sections[0].fields[b].validations && 
                             group.sections[0].fields[b].validations.required
                           ).length
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (var a= 0; a<66; ++a) {
    var requiredFieldsInPart = 0;

        for (var b=0; b<$scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields.length; ++b) {
         try {
             console.log($scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[b]["validations"]["required"]);
             requiredFieldsInPart += 1;//put this line inside 'try' block will do
         } catch (e) {
             console.log(e);
         }             
         }
}
```